# programme cant read single data from doubly linked list

Tags: c++

I have read my file using double linked list and also printed it. This is the execution

```
ID  A1(30) A2(50) MST(30)FE(100)
1234    15  25  20  50
9138    20  30  20  70 
3124    30  35  30  80
4532    16  12  10  75  
5678    20  30  20  30
6134    25  30  20  20 
7874    30  5   10  35
8026    5   22  12  40 
9893    30  20  20  56
```

but I want to add each data in A(30) row with the data in A(50) row in a function but I have no idea how to since the file was read in doubly linked list and I have no idea with working in linked list. This is the code I am implementing but it returns the value of zero when I try to add it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class student{
    private:

        int id;
        int A150;
        int A140;
        int A130;
        int A230;
        int A250;
        int MST20;
        int MST30;
        int FEcs101;
        int FEcs110;
        string Fname;
        string Lname;

    public:
        void setid(int nid ){
            id=nid;
        }
        int getid(){
            return id;
        }

        void setA150(int nA150){
            A150=nA150;
        }
        int getA150(){
            return A150;
        }

        void setA140(int nA140){
            A140=nA140;
        }
        int getA140(){
            return A140;
        }

        void setA130(int nA130){
            A130=nA130;
        }
        int getA130(){
            return A130;
        }

        void setA230(int nA230){
            A230=nA230;
        }
        int getA230(){
            return A230;
        }

        void setA250(int nA250){
            A250=nA250;
        }
        int getA250(){
            return A250;
        }

        void setMST20(int nMST20){
            MST20=nMST20;
        }
        int getMST20(){
            return MST20;
        }
        void setMST30(int nMST30){
            MST30=nMST30;
        }
        int getMST30(){
            return MST30;
        }
        void setFEcs101(int nFEcs101){
            FEcs101=nFEcs101;
        }
        int getFEcs101(){
            return FEcs101;
        }

        void setFEcs110(int nFEcs110){
            FEcs110=nFEcs110;
        }
        int getFEcs110(){
            return FEcs110;
        }

        void setFname(string nFname){
            Fname=nFname;
        }
        string getFname(){
            return Fname;
        }

        void setLname(string nLname){
            Lname=nLname;
        }
        string getLname(){
            return Lname;
        }
};

class node{
    private:
    student data;
    node *next;
    node *prev;
    node *head;
    node *tail;
    public:
    node(){
        head=NULL;
        tail=NULL;
    }
    ~node(){
        cout<<"sample not clear decontructor"<<endl;
    }
    void readfilecs110();
    void readfilestudent();
    void appendnode(node *pnode);
    void add();
};

void node::appendnode(node *pnode)
{

    if (head == NULL) {    
      head = pnode;       
      pnode->prev = NULL;
   }
   else {
      tail->next = pnode;  
      pnode->prev = tail;
   }
   tail = pnode;        
   pnode->next = NULL;  
}

void discard_line(ifstream &in);

void node::readfilecs110(){
    node *pnode;
    ifstream cs110;
    int id=0;
    int A130=0;
    int A250=0;
    int MST30=0;
    int FEcs110=0;
    cs110.open("CS110.txt");
    discard_line(cs110);
    while(cs110>>id>>A130>>A250>>MST30>>FEcs110){
        pnode=new node;
        pnode->data.setid(id);
        pnode->data.setA130(A130);
        pnode->data.setA250(A250);
        pnode->data.setMST30(MST30);
        pnode->data.setFEcs110(FEcs110);
        appendnode(pnode);
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
double sum(double pgrade, double bgrade){
    double sum1;
    sum1=pgrade+bgrade;
    return sum1;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//THIS IS THE IMPLEMENTATION///////////////////////////
void node::add(){
    node *pnode;
    int A1;
    int A2;
    int sus;
    A1=pnode->data.getA140();
    A2=pnode->data.getA150();
    sus=sum(A1,A2);
    cout<<sus<<endl;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(){
    node cs;
    cs.readfilecs110();
    cs.add();




}


void discard_line(ifstream &in)
{
    char c;

    do
        in.get(c);
    while (c!='\n');
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with this code:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//THIS IS THE IMPLEMENTATION///////////////////////////
void node::add(){
    node* pnode(this->head);
    while (pnode){
        sus = sum(pnode->data.getA140(),pnode->data.getA150());
        std::cout << sum(pnode->data.getA140(),pnode->data.getA150()); << std::endl;
        pnode = pnode->next;
    }
}
```

You basically need to get the head of the list(`pnode`) and do your calculation on this `pnode` (which in the first iteration is your first list element) when you have done your calculation, you set your `pnode` to the next node from where you have been, and do your calculation again. You do this as long as you haven't reached a `nullptr` (which means as long you haven't reached the end of your list)
Another thing you should think about is the following: your student-class has all all data-members set to private, but you are writing setters and getters for every single one of them so that you can access and modify them. Why don't you make them public instead, and get rid of all these (in this case unnecessary) functions?
Last thing i want to mention is according to your header `<stdlib.h>`. Since you are writing C++, you should always prefer the C++ headers over the headers for C. C++ headers that also do exist in C begin with an "c". To make this more clear,  use `<cstdlib>` (which is for C++) rather then `<stdlib.h>` (which is for C).

Comment: I have tried to implement your code but the result is still giving me 0.I have also tried to use the for loop for                                                        (pnode=head; pnode != NULL; pnode = pnode->next) but still the answer is 0

Comment: Its not that my Code is wrong, neither is your approach with ``` for (pnode=head; pnode != NULL; pnode = pnode->next)```, but what you trying to add in your function are the students data members "A140" and "A150". The Problem simply is, that you never set those Parameters in your program (so they are always zero). You only set the parameters "A130", "A250", "MST30" and "FEcs110" for your students when you are reading the file.
So when you go into your "sum"-function and try to add two of those parameters, you should get an output :)

Comment: oh thanks..that was the problem..i didn't initialize some parameters also my variables were misplaced in the other file I previously read..NOw its working fine..Thanks

Comment: You should click on the tick next to the top of my answer, below the rating - buttons. This helps the community to see that your problem is solved :)